# Viewing MAMP site on iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, local, mamp

I'm compiling my website with [Hammer for Mac](http://hammerformac.com) and running the site in a local environment with MAMP.

Now, I'm able to view the site on my iPhone when visiting `10.0.1.2/project-name/html` but for some reason it's not reading the paths correctly, which means things like stylesheets are missing.

My CSS looks like this in the page source:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/base.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/form.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/layout.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/skeleton.css'>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong. I'd just like an easy way to view local sites on other devices.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the full path it is outputting when you view it like that? (you can use the latest version of safari on the Mac to 'web inspect' the HTML on the iPhone/iPad when it's plugged in and see whats outputting..